# Mootools Select filtering

Tags: javascript, filter, mootools

I would like to show specific `<li>` elements when I click on one of the options from such a `<select>`:

```
<select>
    <option value="f_chzn_g_0">Group One</option>
    <option value="f_chzn_g_4">Group Two</option>
</select>
```

This is my `<li>`'s which would get filtered to show only selected group.

```
<ul>
    <li id="f_chzn_g_0" class="group-result">Group One</li>
    <li id="f_chzn_o_1" class="active-result group-option" style="">one</li>
    <li id="f_chzn_o_2" class="active-result group-option" style="">two</li>
    <li id="f_chzn_o_3" class="active-result group-option" style="">three</li>
    <li id="f_chzn_g_4" class="group-result">Group Two</li>
    <li id="f_chzn_o_5" class="active-result group-option" style="">one</li>
    <li id="f_chzn_o_6" class="active-result group-option" style="">two</li>
    <li id="f_chzn_o_7" class="active-result group-option" style="">three</li>
</ul>
```

Can someone help me out with this? It all has to be in Mootools. Thanks!

Comment: `each` for ul li's with if statement checking when it start until next .group-result, well having troble with the last part. Not really familiar with mootools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a state variable that tracks whether you're in the selected group when iterating over the `li` elements. Assuming that you show `li` elements by adding the `active-result` class, something like the following should work:

```
function showSelectedListItems(ulElem, selectedId) {
    var inSelectedGroup = false;

    ulElem.getElements('li').each(function(liElem) {
        if (!inSelectedGroup) {
            if (liElem.id == selectedId) inSelectedGroup = true;
        }
        else {
            if (liElem.hasClass('group-result') inSelectedGroup = false;
            else liElem.addClass('active-result');
        }
    });
});
```